# Function not working properly inside a class instance

Tags: python, function, class, module

I have this module which stores a class, an instance of that class, a counter, and a dictionary:

```
#test_module.py:

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name='name', attr='attr'):
        self.name = name
        self.attr = attr
    def func(self, test_list):
        test_dict[count] = test_list[-1].name + '_' + test_list[-1].attr

test_inst = TestClass()

count = 0
test_dict = {}
```

What I want is for the dictionary to store each consecutive value of the counter (1,2,3...) as a key and the name and attribute of the last class instance in a `test_list`. (All the code here is simplified for the sake of reproducing the problem, the actual number of classes and instances is greater).

In a notebook, I have the following code:

```
from test_module import *
test_list = []
test_list.append(test_inst)
count += 1
test_list_item = test_list[-1]
test_dict[count] = test_list_item.name + '_' + test_list_item.attr


test_list.append(test_inst)
count += 1
test_list_item = test_list[-1]
test_list_item.func(test_list)
```

What now is in the dictionary is:
`{1: 'name_attr', 0: 'name_attr'}`

Why am I getting zero as the second key?
I've tried specifying the count and the `test_dict` as global variables in the `TestClass` definition, but to no avail.

All works OK if I copy the contents of the `test_module` into the notebook, but this is not what I'm after. My goal is to have as much code as possible in the `test_module`. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Linked to a dupe that explains why you're having this problem (`count` in your main module is shadowing the imported `count`), but the actual fix IMO is to make `count` and `test_dict` class variables (i.e. declare them inside your `class TestClass`) rather than go through contortions to let modules modify each others' top-level variables.

Comment: @Samwise, thanks for pointing to the answer! Declaring the counter and dict inside the TestClass doesn't seem a viable option, as there are other classes using them, so I guess they should be separate.

Comment: Regardless, making them top-level variables is going to lead to lots of confusing bugs like this.  You generally want to have mutable state in a mutable object so you can modify it without rebinding variable names.  Given your example, it makes sense to encapsulate it within the class that uses it; there might be a better method in your "real" code.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and the output is

```py
{1: 'name_attr', 2: 'name_attr'}
```

Comment: Did you save the contents of the test_module into a separate file or did you run all the code in the same file?

Comment: As you have done: so two different file.

Comment: Hmm.. That's odd. Which version of Python are you using?